# How we can add same class only for the first group child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to add classes for only the first group listed items in a nested ul li list .

```
<ul>
<li class="first-group">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="first-group"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Which element is the *first group child*? Do you want a jQuery or CSS solution?

Comment: your question is not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ShibinRagh/z87he/

set class wraper div

```
 $('.menu>ul>li').addClass('test');
```

Comment: your code is not correct. http://jsfiddle.net/z87he/1/ it will work on all the elements.

Comment: No , you can check with firebug , please do it

Comment: i know that it can manage with css , you read his question he want to set  class name  only

Answer (score 1):

jQuery

```
$('.list-class>li').addClass('your-class-name')
```

CSS

```
.list-class>li {
    /* your style*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afirst-child)

```
.first-group:first-child{
you class details here
}

element:first-child { style properties }
```